# Value Generator - IndexError: list index out of range - Python

Tags: python, indexing, range, generator

I get this error when running the code below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Reum/Desktop/Generator.py", line 35, in <module>
    print(results[0], results[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I use the while loop to seperate the values by commas instead of this:

```
"'value1', 'value2', ..."
```

I use the if loop inside the while loop to catch the latest output and modify it, so that it doesn't have a comma at the end.

I hope that you can solve my (possibly stupid) question.

```
import sys, time

mode = input('Mode:' + ' ')

if mode == 'letters' or mode == 'Letters':
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    letters = True
elif mode == 'numbers' or mode == 'Numbers':
    chars = '0123456789'
    numbers = True
elif mode == 'custom' or mode == 'Custom':
    chars = 'abcde' #Enter some custom chars between the quotation marks.
    custom = True

length = input('Length:' + ' ')
suffix = input('Suffix:' + ' ')

if letters:
    variations = 26 ** int(length)
elif numbers:
    variations = 10 ** int(length)
elif custom:
    variations = 5 ** int(length) #Count the numbers of chars from above and replace the 5 with the outcome of your brain.

print('Generating...' + ' ' + '(' + str(variations) + ' ' + 'values)')

results = []

for counter in range(int(length)):
    char = [x for x in chars]
    for y in range(counter):
        char = [z + x for x in chars for z in char]
        results = results + char

print(results[0], results[1])
print('Results: \n')

counter = 0

while another_counter < variations:
    sys.stdout.write(results[another_counter] + suffix + ',' + ' ')
    time.sleep(0.005)
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter == variations -1: #Maybe not.
        sys.stdout.write(results[counter] + suffix)

print('Finished generating and displaying the values!')
```

Comment: use this link: [link](http://hastebin.com/udositirit.vhdl)

Comment: In addition to the problem you found, your program will also crash if you choose `numbers` or `custom` mode, and you do unnecessary things like using `'Length:' + ' '` instead of `'Length: '`, creating `char` then overwriting it, and adding `sleep` for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because if you use a `length` input of  `1`,

```
for y in range(counter):
```

is not going to be iterating over anything, so nothing shall be added to your `results`. Resultantly, you will not have anything in the index positions `0` or `1`.

Perhaps you want to add `1` to your for-loop range.

---

**Demo:**

You can see this if you insert `print('counter is ' + str(counter))` in your `counter` for-loop:

```
Mode: letters
Length: 1
Suffix: pup
Generating... (26 values)
counter is 0
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 39, in 0
>   builtins.IndexError: list index out of range

Then evidently

```
>>>for x in range(0): print(x)
```

doesn't print anything (*this is the behavior you are having*).